# query pandas dataframe with integer in first level of multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I'm having trouble with pandas MultiIndex, if the first index is an integer.
I could not find this question, so maybe I'm doing something wrong here?

I use pandas version '0.16.2'

Example:

in:

```
data2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10), 
                index = [['a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','c','c'],
                         [ 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 , 0]])
data2.ix[['b','c']]
```

out:

```
            0
b 5  0.295579
  6  0.691801
  7  0.386504
  8  0.602777
c 9  0.269147
  0  0.029509
```

but with integers in the first index-level it doesn't seem to work:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10), 
                index = [[ 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 3], 
                         ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']])
data.ix[[2,3]]
```

out:

```
        0
1 c  0.437728
  d  0.785359
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `loc` instead of `ix`:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10), 
                index = [[ 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 3], 
                         ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']])
data.loc[[2,3]] 

In [264]: data.loc[[2,3]]
Out[264]: 
            0
2 e  0.846643
  f  0.200234
  g  0.298223
  h  0.766459
3 i  0.860181
  j  0.980182
```

For ix it's strange why it's not working because from [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html):

> However, when an axis is integer based, ONLY label based access and not positional access is supported
>   Thus, in such cases, it’s usually better to be explicit and use .iloc or .loc.

You index values are integer so they are should be analysed as labels:

```
In [271]: data.index.levels[0]
Out[271]: Int64Index([1, 2, 3], dtype='int64')
```

But they recommended to use `loc` in such cases to be more explicit.

Comment: Thanks Anton, but do you know why is it different with integers? In my opinion this is pretty confusing...

Comment: @ChristophDiefenthal `.ix` only works with labels when the index is integer-based. That is indeed confusing and the source of the motivation that created `loc` and `iloc`.

Comment: @PaulH: I see - so `.ix` it works fine with `data=pd.DataFrame(...index = [ 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 3])` but not with MultiIndex's. Are we supposed to use `.ix` at all?

Comment: i never use it. my understanding is that it was retained for backwards compatibility, but not much else. @ChristophDiefenthal